# Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?

Tags: suporte, faq, perguntas, respostas, responder-a-si-mesmo

Primeiramente, venho postando perguntas comuns, algumas que eu mesmo fiz/respondi no SO em inglês, e as postando aqui no SO em português de forma à ter as mesmas também disponível em português.

Eu suponho que as mesmas regras para todos os sites da comunidade estejam valendo, logo não vejo problemas nisso. Além de que respostas melhores serão sempre consideradas.

[Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Estou errado ?

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: Relatado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422/3635

Answer (score 29):

Não. A resposta e a pergunta serem de um mesmo autor é irrelevante e deve ser lidada (upvotes, downvotes, flags, etc) como se fossem de autores diferentes.

Não vejo nada de errado em prover uma resposta caso ela exista. Mas como mencionado em um comentário de outra resposta, se for fornecida uma resposta melhor, é de bom-tom o autor des-selecionar a sua resposta e selecionar a outra como correta. Mas é apenas isso, bom-tom, etiqueta, nada mais.

Assim como "esperar algumas horas para responder sua própria pergunta": se fosse tão importante assim, não haveria o botão de autoresposta na própria interface!

No fim das contas, o que importa pra comunidade é a presença de uma (ou várias respostas), não importa quem respondeu!

Comment: Concordo com você! Mas, acompanhando o número de autorrespostas que tem surgido, parece que está ocorrendo um abuso desse recurso. Eu acho que isso não é benéfico para o Beta. 

Boa parte das perguntas são respondidas pelo próprio autor, o que é bem desmotivador para quem tem interesse em responder e ajudar. A impressão que fica é que nem vale a pena ficar monitorando novas perguntas porque ela provavelmente já tem uma resposta. E aí o pessoal pode começar a debandar do Beta.

Comment: Será que tem como coletar estatísticas disso? De quantas perguntas foram respondidas pelo próprio autor?

Comment: @VictorHugo: Tem o http://data.stackexchange.com/ mas como o SOPT é beta, parece que não tem por lá. A alternativa é sequestrar o Gabe e pedir os dados como resgate. ;-)

Comment: hahaha! Interessante esse data.SE

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy O Stack Exchange não negocia com terroristas, e todos os funcionários são treinados em combate armado contra esse tipo de situação :p

Answer (score 17):

Não há problema em se responder à própria pergunta, inclusive os usuários são encorajados a fazê-lo sempre que tiverem algum conhecimento útil e quiserem compartilhá-lo com a comunidade. O próprio sistema facilita isso, através de um *checkbox* logo abaixo da pergunta em si (quando a mesma está sendo formulada):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguns pontos devem ser observados, no entanto:

- Esse é um site de **perguntas e respostas**, não um fórum de discussão ou um blog, portanto seu conteúdo será melhor aceito se colocado na forma de uma pergunta e sua respectiva resposta.
- Verifique se sua pergunta [está dentro do escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e se ela [já não foi feita antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Consulte o guia ["Como fazer uma boa pergunta"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para outros pontos que vale a pena considerar. Uma pergunta de qualidade tem muito mais chance de ser percebida como uma contribuição genuína à comunidade, e portanto bem recebida (e votada).

  - Em particular, certifique-se que a pergunta é "respondível" por outras pessoas que não seu autor. É comum faltar na pergunta informações chave para sua solução, o que com frequência acaba levando-a a ser [suspensa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) como "não está claro o que você está perguntando". Se sua resposta se baseia em fatos que não estão explicitamente citados na pergunta, são somente de conhecimento seu, é provável que sua pergunta sofra o mesmo destino.
- Dê abertura para respostas diferentes da sua. Às vezes você tem certeza de que sabe a melhor resposta, mas aí aparece alguém com uma solução ainda melhor, talvez abordando a questão de um outro ângulo que você não havia previsto. Receba-as tão bem quanto receberia respostas nas suas perguntas não respondidas, votando (e talvez aceitando) de acordo.

  - Detalhe: uma resposta do próprio autor não aparece necessariamente no topo das demais respostas, *mesmo se aceita*, diferentemente das respostas a perguntas de outros autores. De modo que não há por que hesitar em aceitar a própria resposta, mesmo na presença de respostas "melhores", caso você ainda sinta que a sua é a mais satisfatória.
- Por fim, não abuse: há casos de usuários perguntando e respondendo a própria pergunta várias vezes em sequência, numa espécie de "monólogo", sem nenhuma razão aparente. Esse problema era mais acentuado durante a "infância" do site (para mais detalhes, ver [minha resposta anterior, em arquivo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/168/2)), em que perguntas populares no SOen e/ou demasiadamente superficiais para caracterizar "um problema real do AP" eram feitas com o intuito único de acumular [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

  Esse tipo de comportamento, mesmo nos dias de hoje, é mal visto por muitos membros da comunidade (ainda que estritamente falando não viole nenhuma regra). Afinal, o objetivo último do site é criar um repositório de conhecimento extenso e de qualidade, o sistema de pontuação é apenas um pretexto. Assim, caso decida por fazer muitas perguntas cuja reposta já sabe, faça isso com moderação, sem perder o foco na qualidade, e se possível intercalando com perguntas "reais" e/ou respostas às dúvidas de outras pessoas. Desse modo evitará passar uma impressão ruim, mesmo que inadvertidamente.

Comment: A resposta já era ótima e agora ficou atual, pena não ter mais votos. Deveria ter até aceitação por ser bem completa.

Answer (score 9):

Eu pessoalmente fico desanimado quando vejo isso. Alguns diriam que é cortesia esperar algumas horas antes de responder.

O desanimo é devido a pensar que se o autor já adotou uma resposta (a sua própria), qual o motivo de querer responder de um jeito diferente.

Agora, quando o autor expressa que a sua própria resposta está incompleta, ou que queria algo com melhor desempenho, o animo volta.

Comment: É realmente.. Mas aí que está, se você têm uma resposta melhor, simplesmente poste-a, a comunidade irá valorizá-la mais que a do autor da pergunta. Eu particularmente espero bastante tempo antes de "aceitar" minha própria resposta. Que ao meu ver, isso sim é errôneo, responder e não importa quais as respostas que você receba, selecionar a sua, mesmo que existam melhores.

Comment: Eu não vejo problemas nisso. Mas aqui vejo problemas no "farming" pelo menos nesse início de site. Não vai fazer bem ao rumo do site encher de questões já respondidas no SO. Claro que pode, mas não agora.

Comment: @bigown Você está começando a me convencer...

Comment: Nem sempre a resposta é óbvia. Muitas vezes eu tenho uma teoria, e colocar ela em prática leva todo um tempo, apesar de gostar de ajudar o povo, não tenho tempo para fazer isso o dia todo, então tento me concentrar nas questões não respondidas. Então você vai me dizer para colocar minhas teorias não testadas. Vou dizer, algumas vezes no StackOverflow pesquisei um monte para colocar uma teoria altamente pertinente, e eu recebi downvotes. Percebi que os outros que responderam são os que mais gostam de pisar. Minha esperança é que a versão brasileira tenha menos rivalidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto E o pior é que eu já tive posição contrária ao que estou pregando em outro site da rede quando iniciou as atividades. Mas vi que se começa mal, fica muito complica consertar depois. A meta é começar perfeito, nada menos que isso, aí tem chance de começar bom e ir bem.

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Espero o mesmo que você, embora já percebi, como era esperado, que alguns comportamentos ruins vão continuar aqui e provavelmente virão outros. Não digo que esse especificamente  já seja visível mas o que mais me importa agora é que o site cresça organicamente. Todos os sites que não cresceram assim, afundaram.

Answer (score 0):

Concordo com a resposta do próprio autor desde que alguém já tenha respondido ou passado um determinado tempo.

Como disse o amigo acima @Marcos Zolnowski, isso está acontecendo com muita frequência. Hoje mesmo me deparei com uma pergunta onde 30 segundos depois o autor respondeu, e detalhe, estava tudo MUITO BEM EDITADO.

O pessoal que entra, não presta atenção no autor e já vai clicando no "up vote", isso aconteceu comigo. Fiz questão de voltar lá e dar um "uncheck". O autor fez a pergunta, respondeu a própria e tá ganhando reputação á doidado.

Conclusão: Acho interessante o próprio autor responder mas depois de alguns critérios, tá ficando ridícula a coisa.

Comment: Informação relevante: essa discussão se deu originalmente nos primeiros dias do beta privado do site. Naquele momento, não parecia uma boa idéia trazer grandes volumes de perguntas artificiais de uma vez (coisa que ocorreu). Não há problema em responder à própria pergunta, o sistema inclusive te dá a opção de postar a pergunta e a resposta simultaneamente (que que significa que isso é [incentivado pela própria ferramenta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: Um outro uso para essa ferramenta que é o SO é documentar dúvidas antigas e problemas que você mesmo já resolveu. Talvez para poder preservar sua solução, para ajudar a outros, ou ainda para encontrar uma melhor que a sua (você pode responder uma pergunta que o autor já o fez). Isso acaba funcionando quase como um *blog*. Mas é importante que a pergunta deve ao menos parecer uma pergunta real e respondível, coisas artificiais não ficam bem. E se for uma tradução do SOen, lembrar de informar o link para a fonte.

Comment: Revivendo a sua resposta, a opção de responder a própria questão, isso é, perguntar e responder simultâneamente é incentivado e válido. Uma pergunta que ainda não tenha sido feita e não existe ainda no SO pode ser feito e respondida, pois o autor pode ter conseguido obter uma resposta (que na maioria das vezes é fruto de muita pesquisa). Esse assunto é padrão do meta, portanto um exemplo pode ser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call