# Respostas na linguagem errada devem ser excluídas?

Tags: debate, respostas, exclusão

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49786/reconhecer-repeti%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-palavras-na-string/50542#50542) foi sinalizada como "não é uma resposta", pois a pergunta é sobre Java e a resposta está em Perl. Ela até começa assim:

> Ok, ok, ok, não é Java...

Pergunto: vocês acham que a resposta deve ser excluída? Ou talvez receber votos contra? Ela está claramente fora de lugar, isso é estranho. Mas perder um conteúdo potencialmente útil (pra ser sincero, eu não entendo bem aqueles hieróglifos) vale a pena? O que fazer com ela? Talvez providenciar uma pergunta onde ela se encaixe?

Comment: Em tempo: pena que o autor excluiu os comentários dele abaixo da resposta, eram interessantes.

Comment: Moderadores conseguem ver comentários excluídos? Se sim, pode ser pertinente colocar em *quote* os comentários dele.

Comment: @Victor Não concordo. Se ele quis apagar, acho que devemos respeitá-lo, por mais que sejam comentários legais.

Comment: @Victor Podemos ver os comentários excluídos, mas só podemos reverter a exclusão daqueles que nós mesmos excluímos. Por esse motivo entendo que eu não devo postar os comentários dele publicamente, já que a vontade dele foi removê-los.

Comment: @bfavaretto https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7109/101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por tudo que eu entendo do padrão de uso da rede a resposta não deve ser removida. Remoções devem ser usadas para casos onde não é uma resposta de fato.

Devemos perguntar o que acontecerá com esta resposta se ela for removida? Como este conteúdo poderá ser substituído?

Claro que se a resposta tem graves problemas, é um *spam*, linguagem abusiva ou coisa do gênero, o conteúdo não deveria estar no *site*.

Se o conteúdo deveria estar no *site* e apenas o local está errado devemos sinalizar para que isto possa ser corrigido.

Talvez ele deva ser convertido em comentário. E provavelmente deveria ter ferramentas melhoras para deixar clara essa intenção da comunidade para os moderadores saberem o que fazer ou mesmo deixar a comunidade fazer a conversão com um número determinado de sinalizações de usuário de alta reputação. Em alguns casos um simples alerta para que aquilo deva ser um comentário já bastaria.

Talvez deveria deixar claro para o autor que ele deve fazer uma edição na pergunta dele. Quem sabe até algum usuário fazer a edição para ajudar o autor original.

Em alguns casos a sinalização deve indicar que a resposta deveria ser na verdade uma pergunta nova.

Acho que vocês entenderam. Se a resposta não é vandalismo ou só causa problemas ela deve ser encaminhada para se transformar de forma automática ou manualmente em alguma outra coisa. O conteúdo deve ser preservado. Não é para haver uma simples remoção.

Este caso a resposta cabe em outro lugar? Deve ser um comentário? Deve ser uma edição? Deve ser outra pergunta? Deve ser resposta em outro lugar onde ela cabe perfeitamente?

Não.

#### Então deve ser removida?

Não.

Ela deve continuar no *site*. Quem sabe ela ajude na resposta de alguma forma.

#### Deve ser negativada?

Não sei, talvez. Não me pareceu má fé, pelo contrário. Mas principalmente não sei se merece negativo porque não sei se é útil ou não. Mesmo inútil, uma resposta deve permanecer no *site*. Inutilidade e lugar errado são coisas diferentes.

Pode ser útil. Mas não acho que merece destaque naquele contexto.

Certamente não vou positivar uma resposta em outra linguagem e se puder recomendar diria para ninguém votar. Talvez um positivo cairia bem em outro caso onde a resposta fosse sensacional e fornecesse algo algo memorável mesmo não sendo o que o autor pediu. Mas negativar eu também não faria.

Não recrimino quem o faça. Acho que o voto negativo não estaria completamente errado. Muito menos acho que ele seja o mais certo a fazer.

Por mim deixar a pergunta paradinha lá é a melhor solução.

Obviamente ela não receberá a recompensa. É óbvio, certo?

Apesar de eu não me preocupar mais com isto eu continuo achando que conteúdos ruins e que de uma forma ou outra trazem problemas devem ficar longe do *site*. Este caso nem de perto se encaixa nestes critérios. Sem liberar tudo como alguns gostariam, mesmo que o discurso seja que não é tudo que pode, eu acho que quanto mais conteúdo bom, melhor. Mesmo quando ele não esteja no lugar certo.

Sutilezas em outros casos podem me fazer ter uma decisão diferente.

Comment: Também acho que deixar onde está é uma opção, mas não sei se é melhor que pendurá-la em uma pergunta à parte (que teria de ser nova, acho que não temos duplicata disso pra perl). "Já então" (esses tugas estão me influenciando!), tem uns 5 *feature-requests* aí na sua resposta ;)

Comment: Se alguém fizer uma pergunta só para pendurá-la acho que é ok. Mas não acho que precise necessariamente fazer só para deixar a resposta no lugar certo. Aí acho que pode deixar orgânico. A única coisa que acho errado (mas também não vou morrer por causa disto) é removê-la.

Comment: Vale dizer que ela já foi removida via fila de análise, mas eu desfiz a exclusão, já que trouxe a discussão aqui para o meta. Se a maioria achar que devemos sim removê-la, podemos remover novamente.

Comment: Concordo com as conclusões e com os argumentos. A resposta pode não ser uma **resposta** ao problema, mas tem seu valor se alguém tiver curiosidade sobre o assunto. Isso não significa que mereça algum destaque. No momento ela está no fundo de uma pilha de 7 respostas, e é a única sem nenhum voto. Se alguém achar que a solução é *sensacional* que vote, mas acho que ela tá muito bem lá como uma nota de rodapé ou um "Você sabia?" de livro acadêmico.

Comment: Acabou de aparecer um caso similar (resposta em outra linguagem), mas diferente (não acrescenta muito, o algoritmo já estava em outra resposta): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51043/74. Nesse caso, parece mais estranho deixar como está. (CC @Gabe)

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo que ela é ainda menos "interessante" que a original, mas o mesmo raciocínio do bigown se aplica. Ela é uma resposta... Não acho que precisa ser removida. Quanto a *votos*, fica a critério de cada um.

Comment: @Gabe Eu não concordaria em remover, mas preferia a criação de uma pergunta "sintética" sobre swift para abrigá-la.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não sei... Me parece trabalho demais pra resolver um problema de menos.

Answer (score 1):

Boa gente,
   esta foi a primeira resposta que dei no SO-pt (apagado):

consegui vários comentários zangados comigo!: -- o pessoal acha insultuoso que se responda a um problema usando uma linguagem diferente!

Tentei comentar -- e dizem-me que não estou a usar bem os comentátrios.

Aprentemente fui parar a "fila de exclusão" (que não sei o que é)

(dois parágrafos apagados)

Um abraço

JJoao

**EDIT: Desculpem**

Por favor ignorem o meu mau feito, e rezinguice! Vamos mas é 
concentrar em coisas interessantes em programas, em algoritmos e em ideas.

Comment: Ei, espera aí! Eu abri esta discussão justamente para evitar isso! Essa nossa comunidade tem bastante flexibilidade, até às vezes onde acho que não deve (não é o caso da sua resposta). E na minha experiência o SO inglês costuma ser muito menos tolerante.

Comment: Foi curioso ter a primeira pessoa que acha que o SO é mais receptivo. Não vi ninguém zangado lá na resposta. Raramente vejo usuários experientes zangados no *site*. Não vi ninguém achando insulto ter aquela resposta. Será que os comentários foram apagados? Bom, se forma, mostra que eles é que estavam errados. Acho que você entendeu tudo errado e está tirando conclusões precipitadas. O que pode acontecer de novo aqui. As pessoas estão tentando ajudar a ficar tudo certo. Você ficou zangado? Me pareceu que sim.

Comment: Bom dia professor. Fui seu aluno na Universidade do Minho e espero que continue no site. Entenda que aqui apenas discutimos os assuntos do site para manter a qualidade do mesmo. Como a "resposta exótica" é diferente de tudo que já aconteceu no site, foi trazida para aqui a discussão saudável sobre a mesma. É um habito da comunidade para tentar manter a qualidade do site. Um Abraço

Comment: Espero que reveja a sua saída do SOpt. As discussões criadas por uma situação de pergunta/resposta são ótimas e até mesmo fundamentais para a comunidade.

Comment: Entendo que o nosso site possa parecer estranho ou mesmo hostil com tantas regras, ferramentas esquisitas ("filas" disso e daquilo), e uns malucos como eu que transformam tudo em um grande debate. Mas como disse o @JorgeB., tudo o que queremos é garantir algum nível de qualidade. Fiquei muito feliz com a edição desta sua resposta, e assino embaixo da última frase: *concentrar em coisas interessantes em programas, em algoritmos e em ideias*, no fundo isso é o que importa mesmo. Seja bem-vindo :)

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, desde o momento em que a pergunta foi feita constava a *tag* Java. Se o autor da pergunta está sendo especifico apontando que a resolução do problema é em Java, espera-se respostas em... Java (?).

Eu penso que as tags não servem unicamente para ajudar a encontrar uma determinada pergunta/resposta por palavra-chave, mas também valem como uma forma de organizar melhor a nossa comunidade.

Se o StackOverflow tivesse algum tipo de restrição para fazer perguntas (por exemplo: somente usuários com 50+ de reputação) até seria discutível, visto que ter respostas em várias linguagens poderiam ser úteis em situações futuras onde um usuário novato não poderia criar uma pergunta. Mas nossa comunidade é aberta, qualquer um pode perguntar independente da reputação. Se for o caso de alguém ter a mesma dúvida em Perl basta que ele crie uma pergunta para abordar o assunto. Afinal é isso que movimenta a comunidade, **perguntas**!

Caso o usuário queira compartilhar com a comunidade algo que ele considera útil e importante basta simplesmente criar uma pergunta e respondê-la, [ele próprio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), [não tem problema algum nisso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/37). Isso sim vai útil para futuras pesquisas pelo assunto e não responder uma pergunta onde espera-se respostas em **C#** com outra linguagem, só pelo fato de saber como resolver em **Java**. Pra mim isso é desorganização.

Comment: É que o sistema é feito para que as pessoas votem para destruir as coisas. Ninguém disse pra ele que ele poderia criar outra pergunta. Tem muito mais chance de o conteúdo acabar deletado do que realocado. Então o mínimo seria deixar onde está (transformar em comentário acho estranho, muito código inline).

Comment: Não sou a favor de negativar a resposta, mas colocá-la no devido lugar sim. E o devido lugar, na minha opinião é em uma pergunta relacionada ao assunto mas implementada Perl. Na resposta em questão, nem é citado a linguagem, como isso seria útil em uma busca no Google por exemplo? 'como reconhecer repetições em uma string em perl' não apontaria para aquela pergunta tampouco aquela resposta.

Comment: Ou alguém coloca a resposta "no lugar", ou ela fica onde está. Assim ela tem *alguma* chance de ser encontrada. Excluída, a chance cai para zero.

Comment: Que seja, se a comunidade considera melhor desta forma, por mim tudo bem (mesmo não concordando). Só para deixar claro então, se uma resposta que deveria estar em C# surgir na fila de análise por ter sido respondida em Java, o "parece ok" está permitido visto que isso fará ela ser encontrada futuramente?

Comment: Você sempre pode pular o item na fila também. Ou trazer a discussão para o meta. Não é que algo "está permitido", eu não decreto isso. Só estou defendendo uma comunidade que não exclua rápido demais conteúdo que não seja absolutamente inútil. Se o conteúdo tem valor, que se discuta o que fazer com ele, e se decida caso a caso.

Comment: Não é o que está sendo feito? A discussão, creio eu, foi aberta justamente para saber o que deve ser feito em casos como esse. Uma resposta há de ter, óras.

Comment: @renan, outro dia fiz algo parecido, comecei a resolver uma pergunta e acabei enchendo a resposta de firulas, acabei postando a resposta sem responder a pergunta em si, até que você me apontou o erro e eu prometi retificar. Nestes dois casos existia uma resposta útil fora do contexto. Ao meu ver o melhor seria haver uma forma de sinalizar as respostas, da mesma forma que sinalizamos as perguntas.

Comment: @TobyMosque então, mas a discussão é para saber se respostas com linguagem diferente da qual foi perguntava devem ser excluídas. No seu caso era uma pergunta sobre Javascript e sua resposta estava de acordo, inclusive tem meu upvote :)