# Como tratar uma resposta em linguagem diferente?

Tags: debate, respostas

Hoje me deparei com uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305172/5043) em PHP que provavelmente responde a dúvida do usuário, porém a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305147/5043) não cita na descrição e as tags também não sugerem que o AP está usando essa linguagem. Ela é claramente uma pergunta sobre Javascript. No caso, negativei a resposta e pedi que melhorasse, talvez removendo a linguagem PHP e deixando apenas o Javascript, mas não sei se agi direito.

Pesquisando, notei essa [discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2465/respostas-na-linguagem-errada-devem-ser-exclu%C3%ADdas/2468#2468) no meta que trata justamente disso. Embora eu discorde um pouco da resposta com maior votação (não há uma resposta aceita), creio que ela ficou um pouco "em cima do muro". Não concordo com tudo o que se diz nela, afinal não acho certo esse tipo de resposta, por alguns motivos:

- Pode surgir uma pergunta na linguagem correta que poderíamos utilizar essa resposta, porém não vamos nem conseguir encontrá-la através de filtros e pesquisas, já que ela está em um lugar errado;
- Isso pode dar espaço a outras respostas em outras linguagens. Começamos com PHP, logo teremos uma em C#, outra em Java, outra em Python, outra em ASP, enfim...
- Pode nem ser interessante para o AP, mas como ele vai julgar isso se a resposta está correta?

Eu agi bem? O que posso fazer para melhorar? Ou, como citado na resposta da outra discussão, deixo ela paradinha lá? O que fazer nesses casos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Pode surgir uma pergunta na linguagem correta que poderíamos utilizar essa resposta, porém não vamos nem conseguir encontrá-la através de filtros e pesquisas, já que ela está em um lugar errado;

Isto não é argumento.  Não precisa encontrá-la, uma coisa não invalida a outra.

> Isso pode dar espaço a outras respostas em outras linguagens. Começamos com PHP, logo teremos uma em C#, outra em Java, outra em Python, outra em ASP, enfim...

Pode, mas não acontece. Se acontecer com frequência podemos ver isto. Temos problemas bem maiores. Precisam nos concentrar neles. Nem sei se isto é problema. De qualquer o negativo tá ali se realmente achar que merece.

> Pode nem ser interessante para o AP, mas como ele vai julgar isso se a resposta está correta?

Da mesma forma que ele julga em qualquer situação. Se tiver outra na linguagem dele que atende bem ele escolhe aquela. Se ele não tiver noção alguma, o fato desta resposta não existir não vai mudar nada. Se for a única, cabe a ele decidir se deve ficar sem aceitação. Ele pode até aceitar esta, pode ser que resolveu bem o problema, mesmo que tenha outra na linguagem que ele quer, mas que não resolve bem. É problema dele decidir se atendeu bem o que ele quer.

Geralmente isto causa menos problema do que uma aceitação totalmente aloprada com profundo desconhecimento do assunto em uma resposta na linguagem certa. Pior ainda quando a pessoa aceita uma resposta errada porque não gosta de alguém que deu outra resposta melhor, ou que a resposta é de "amigo" dele, e coisas do tipo.

Respondi cada ponto, mas acho até que aqui é duplicata porque o que deve fazer já parece estar respondi na pergunta onde o assunto foi discutido. Se acha que precisa de melhoria de resposta lá ou que precisa de mais votos ou aceitação para definir mais claramente pode por uma recompensa lá. Ou pode só chamar atenção do AP (no meta, no caso o bfavaretto) para ver se ele esqueceu de aceitar ou não tem nada que ele queira mesmo.

Como lá diz, negativar pode ser uma boa, se não for ideológico, se realmente a resposta não é muito adequada ali.

Neste caso que não está muito claro que linguagem é (por isso aceitei que esta não é 100% duplicata), ajudar o AP a definir isso melhor é sempre uma boa. Só não vai editar a pergunta pra colocar ou tirar uma *tag*, sem ter certeza se é o certo a se fazer. Muitas vezes a pergunta ou os comentários dão dicas de qual linguagem é. H´pa casos, não todos, que ter mais *tags* de linguagem pode ser um indicativo que a pergunta é ampla.

Comment: `Neste caso que não está muito claro que linguagem é`, sobre qual pergunta você diz? Achei que estivesse claro aqui. Não concordo muito com o que você descreveu. Com essa resposta, casos como estes vão continuar a se repetir (resposta sopt -> pergunta no meta -> resposta meta), embora, talvez, não tão frequentemente. Acho que vou esperar um outro ponto de vista.

Comment: No SOen [há uma pergunta semelhante](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290046/2456028). O ponto de vista deles e o meu são bem parecidos. A ideia não é comparar, afinal o SOpt é uma comunidade diferente, portanto coloquei esse link apenas para complementar o que eu penso sobre...

Comment: Falo sobre o exemplo que usou. Não sei porque teria que sempre vir para o meta, mas acho que é o caso de fechar como duplicata. Eu acho que no momento atual sabemos o que acontece ou não e não adianta mais tentar disciplinar muito, eu era mais rígido no começo pra formar uma posição, agora o que tiver que acontecer acontecerá. Lá no MSO a resposta mais votada diz o mesmo que eu, só de forma mais enfática, negative.

Answer (score -6):

Acredito que algumas atitudes de veteranos são negativas para a comunidade. O perfil de um programador é uma pessoa logica e objetivo e isso se reflete no padrão de perguntas e respostas do site.  Porém, em uma breve analise das perguntas recentes é possível perceber que a grande maioria é feita por usuários novatos que estão utilizando pela primeira vez.

Primeiro gostaria de fazer um desabafo. Quando se entra no Stackoverflow estes padrões para perguntar não são explícitos e o que acontece é que novatos fazem perguntas de maneira ""errada"" e consequentemente são negativados. Eu particularmente passei por isto, em minha primeira pergunta fui negativado sem saber o por que e não entendia o que estava acontecendo, até que alguém me explicou. Porém muitas pessoas acabam saindo logo no começo por conta deste tipo de situação. Acredito que o melhor a se fazer é editar a pergunta e explicar no comentário o que é necessário.

Sobre a resposta que eu fiz em PHP, tenho algumas observações. Primeiramente as tags utilizadas são do que o AP utilizou até então, como não foi dito em momento algum que precisava ser feito de tal maneira, não vi problema em apresentar uma outra solução. Como eu disse, muitas das vezes estudantes iniciantes como é o meu caso e como deve ser o do AP, tentamos utilizar o que sabemos para resolver certa situação, porém não necessariamente são as melhores soluções. Eu mesmo já fiz perguntas relacionadas a PHP e me foi recomendado utilizar JQuery para certa funcionalidade, pois era mais eficiente. Como eu não utilizo JQuery, quando fiz a pergunta não sabia desta possibilidade. E como todo programador sabe, o mais importante é saber a logica do que a linguagem em si. ontem por exemplo ajudei um usuário em um pergunta de Python, porém meu conhecimento é bem básico nesta linguagem, mas apresentando a logica para ele, ele conseguiu resolver o problema.

Concluindo, gostaria que os veteranos fossem mais pacientes e que explicassem a maneira correta de se fazer algo antes de negativar ou simplesmente dizer que é errado tal coisa. Pois este tipo de atitude nada mais faz do que afastar pessoas que poderiam estar contribuindo com a comunidade.

Comment: O problema é que a maioria das pessoas ainda não sabem que o [StackOverflowPT NÃO é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum) e o tratam como tal. Aqui as coisas agem de forma objetiva (ao menos a maior parte do tempo). Usuários novatos entram aqui e geralmente não conhecem as regras, fazem perguntas do tipo fórum (que se gera discussão), não sabem diferenciar comentários de respostas e as vezes nem mesmo levam a sério o site.

Comment: `como não foi dito em momento algum que precisava ser feito de tal maneira`... Discordo, se o usuário postou uma pergunta com as tags que precisava, está claro que a resposta que ele queria era em Javascript. Se ele precisava de uma solução com PHP ou qualquer outra ele teria colocado a tag da linguagem. Isso é inútil. Me faz pensar em postar respostas em perguntas Javascript utilizando ActionScript. O código que ele postou na pergunta já explicita isso também.

Comment: "Usuários novatos entram aqui e geralmente não conhecem as regras, fazem perguntas do tipo fórum (que se gera discussão), não sabem diferenciar comentários de respostas " Qual seu plano pra evitar isto? dar um negativo e voltar para aba anterior? é exatamente disto que estou falando. Quem usa a mais tempo esquece que já foi novato e esquece que essas regras não estão explícitas para quem utiliza a primeira vez.

Comment: O plano é ensinar, alertar, comentar... Geralmente quando fechamos uma pergunta ou resposta de baixa qualidade sempre deixamos um comentário (isso é automático na fila de análise, você não tem reputação suficiente ainda). Há links, descrições, tooltips, avisos, citações espalhados por todo o site, não é difícil de aprender, basta querer. Você diz que não está explícito, mas quando você se cadastra no site já é redirecionado para o tour e outros links são apresentados. Se um usuário quiser mesmo fazer parte do SOpt bastava ele "perder" um ou dois minutos lendo uma página para aprender o básico.

Comment: Aliás, ao fazer uma perguntar, resposta ou qualquer outra coisa no site você sempre é alertado sobre tais coisas. Há links por todos os textos. Um usuário novato ignora esses avisos e sofre as consequências, simples assim, não há o que fazer, a não ser que esses avisos comecem aparecer igual nossos antigos ["amigos popup"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1AXxjJ7AA8)

Comment: Ninguem entra num país novo e faz o que quer sem antes procurar conhecer suas leis, só porque no seu país tais coisas eram permitidas. Quem entra num lugar novo tem por dever procurar saber como ali funciona, o que ela pode e não pode fazer, não é obrigação de quem já está lá passar a mão na cabeça não. Nos cabe sim orientar, mas a quem quer ser orientado, a maioria ta pouco se lixando pras orientações, alguns até nos xingam nos comentários. Cabe a quem chega procurar saber como funciona, e isso é facilmente perceptível pela comunidade, que vai acolher quem quer participar conforme as regras.

Comment: De fato a ferramenta não ajuda muito, dá muito trabalho agradar todo mundo. Há tempos algumas pessoas falam sobre agradar os novatos. Pois bem, os novatos estão qui para ganhar algo. Os veteranos estão principalmente para ajudar, e de graça. Eles precisam fazer mais ainda? Precisam se esforçar para agradar os novatos que não querem se esforçar? Me parece um pedido injusto. E tem gente que desiste antes de começar mesmo. O que sugere fazer para resolver essa questão? As pessoas que já se dedicam horrores aqui se dedicar mais ainda? Por que elas deveriam fazer isto?

Comment: Eu gostaria que os novatos se dedicassem mais e tivessem mais compromisso na hora de fazer uma pergunta, aprender como o site funciona, colaborar, dar de volta o que ganhou do jeito que consegue, e tem várias formas de fazer isto. Empatou? Essa conversa que afasta as pessoas que poderiam estar contribuindo é dita faz tempo, mas não há comprovação disto. Eu sei de muita gente que contribuía e não o faz mais, talvez porque terem cansado de ajudar e não ter o reconhecimento, e ter que repetidas vezes cuidar dessas pessoas que não colabora.

Comment: O histórico mostra justamente o contrário. Quem quer colaborar sempre aprende, entende a cultura do site, insiste, até chegar no ponto certo. E depois elas costumam cansar de ter que lidar com tanto problema. Isso tem muitos casos. Já vi gente que queria colaborar e desistir logo, mas seria que queria colaborar ou por seu ego na frente de tudo e fazer a comunidade se adaptar a ele. Vi casos de pessoas conhecidas indústria que pensam assim, chegam aqui achando que podem determinar que todo mundo será como eles. Mas quero ouvir sugestões efetivas pra melhorar.

Comment: Todos são bem-vindos aqui, desde que a pessoa queira ter uma participação séria, que se comporte como um programador, mesmo que iniciante, os demais não terão muita sorte. A parte da pergunta/resposta parece que não é bem assim, embora eu tenha analisado pouco. E acho que está equivocada na sua visão, não que ela esteja de todo errada, mas não pode adaptar a situação ao que precisa ou que te interessa.