# Erros de comportamento causa remoção de qual usuário? Daquele que pergunta ou daquele que vota?

Tags: suporte, comportamento, voto-contra

Tenho como participação nesse site, vários aspectos, à saber: confrontar meu conhecimento com outros bons profissionais, treinar habilidades de análise de problemas, organizar as ideias e escrever de forma clara, aprender diversificadas abordagens pra um mesmo problema.

Tive uma Curiosidade/Dificuldade então decidi abrir uma nova questão no pt.stackoverflow.com. Veja o link abaixo:

[Buscar Elemento Array pelo Campo de Texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137465/buscar-elemento-array-pelo-campo-de-texto/137473#137473)

Ainda no meu computador (PC), continuei fazendo possíveis combinações e rapidamente cheguei a solução/resposta da minha pergunta. Logo postei, e mais uma vez veja no que deu:

[Saiba mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)

Mas, é a primeira vez que isto ocorreu comigo, não esta claro pra mim, **quem foi removido e porque estou vendo tanto negativações sobre a minha resposta**, acho isso um pouco antiquado, não deveria antes por *melhorar* **editar** a questão e/ou a pergunta.

É chato pensar que além de você ter o prazer participar/contribuir com a comunidade, pessoas negativa sem **ao menos dar uma resposta**.

"Quais", "De que forma", "Como", "Por que"

Normalmente, as perguntas devem ser precisas, objetivas, curtas e claras.

1 - O que houve errado com esta pergunta e reposta?

2 - Meu Comportamento foi incomun?

3 - Fiz má prática ao pergunta e responder em seguida?

Observe, que tirei um print:

[Print Screen](http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/651/902/full/buscar-elemento-array-pelo-campo-de-texto.png)

O que fazer neste caso, ou nada a fazer?

Comment: Jovem, você só tomou 1 negativo na sua resposta. Apareceu **`O usuário foi removido`** porque um usuário do site, que era assíduo e votante excluiu sua conta, logo todos os seus votos foram removidos. Isso aconteceu comigo e alguns outros usuários que tive contato hoje.

Comment: @jbueno Quer dizer que, este mesmo usuário tinha tickt nervoso nos dedos é isso mesmo que entendi?

Comment: Não, você entendeu errado. Quer dizer que o usuário votou em duas perguntas suas há algum tempo atrás e hoje a conta dele foi excluída. A exclusão da conta faz com que os votos sejam revertidos. Ficou mais claro?

Comment: @jbueno Ficou alto e claro. Só me resta uma dúvida, continuo ativo no portal pt.stackoverflow.com podendo dar continuidade com minhas dúvidas e soluções?

Comment: Com certeza. A mensagem se refere ao outro usuário. Você continua normalmente, com o tempo vai ver que votos negativos são comuns por aqui. Na teoria, eles servem para incentivar alguma melhora na publicação, na prática acontece um pouco diferente, mas ainda assim, o voto negativo serve para representar algum descontentamento com a publicação em si e a única "penalidade" por levar um negativo é perder 1 (em perguntas) ou 2 (em respostas) ponto(s) de reputação. Claro que se tomar muitos negativos mostra que a publicação tem algo errado e aí outras medidas serão tomadas, mas é outra história.

Comment: @jbueno Agradeço desde, ja pela atenção dada. Att+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Tenho como participação nesse site, vários aspectos, à saber: confrontar meu conhecimento com outros bons profissionais, treinar habilidades de análise de problemas, organizar as ideias e escrever de forma clara, aprender diversificadas abordagens pra um mesmo problema.

Ótimo!

> não esta claro pra mim, quem foi removido e porque estou vendo tanto negativações sobre a minha resposta, acho isso um pouco antiquado, não deveria antes por melhorar editar a questão e/ou a pergunta.

O negativo é porque alguém achou que a resposta tem algum erro, ou não gostou do que postou, ou não gostou que postou algo que pode ajudar alguém. Não vou entrar no mérito do conteúdo agora, mas eu acho que o voto negativo só deveria ser dado por causa de um erro, ou ser algo inútil.

O ideal é te ajudar salvar a pergunta, mas não é obrigatório. Como a pessoa optou por não dizer nada, não tem mais nada o que fazer.  Só veja se pode melhorar alguma coisa na esperança da pessoa tirar ou receber positivos.

Em casos isolados assim, de uma maneira geral não tem muito o que fazer.

A remoção de usuário não tem nada com este problema. Foi uma coincidência que ocorreu hoje. Coisa rara. Não precisa saber quem foi e não te afeta nada a não ser que perdeu os pontos que tinha ganho quando este usuário votou em alguma coisa sua.

> 1 - O que houve errado com esta pergunta e reposta?
>
> 2 - Meu Comportamento foi incomun?
>
> 3 - Fiz má prática ao pergunta e responder em seguida?

[Não fez nada errado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/37/101). Nada incomum ou má prática. Pelo contrário.

Comment: obrigado, por me esclarecer, então posso continuar com minhas atividades no portal pt.stackoverflow.com numa boa?

Comment: Sim Diogo, pode sim.